# E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 5, mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 369098752

Tags: java, android, realm, out-of-memory

Im trying to download large json files into Realm database. `loadCarbay()` does well, but the `checkTyres()` throws out of memory exception on `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`

I've checked all realm code on closing instance - everything is well. I checked `getLocalInstanceCount()` - it returns 0 before crash. I cannot understand what im doing wrong?

```
void checkLoadData(){
        final boolean hasCarbay = hasCarbay();
        final boolean hasTyres = hasTyres();

        if(!hasPersons()||!hasModels()||!hasDeparts()||!hasCarbay||!hasTyres){
            if(checkWifi(this)){
                if(!progressDialog.isShowing())progressDialog.show();
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        final String holding = ses.getString("holding_url");
                        final String curr = ses.getString("curBaseAAURL");
                        loadBase(holding,curr,"");
                        if(!hasPersons()) {
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_PERSONS_START);
                            loadTablePersons(LoginPageActivity.this, h, STATUS_LOADING_PERSONS_PROGRESS, STATUS_LOADING_PERSONS_END);
                            loadTopicsFromJson(LoginPageActivity.this);
                        }
                        if(!hasModels()){
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_MODELS_START);
                            loadAlfaModels(LoginPageActivity.this,h,STATUS_LOADING_ALFA_PROGRESS,STATUS_LOADING_ALFA_END);
                        }
                        if(!hasDeparts()){
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_WS_LINKS_START);
                            loadDepartments(LoginPageActivity.this);
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_WS_LINKS_END);
                        }
                        if(!hasCarbay){
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_CARBAY_START);
                            loadCarbayData(LoginPageActivity.this,h,STATUS_LOADING_CARBAY_END);
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_CARBAY_END);
                        }
                        if(!hasTyres){
                            h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_TYRE_START);
                            loadTyres(LoginPageActivity.this,h,STATUS_LOADING_TYRE_END);

                        }
                        h.sendEmptyMessage(STATUS_LOADING_TYRE_END);

                    }
                }
                );
                t.start();
            }
            }

    }

    private boolean hasCarbay(){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        long count = realm.where(CarbayBrand.class)
                .count();
        boolean f = count>0;
        realm.close();

        return f;
    }

    private boolean hasTyres(){
        boolean flag = false;
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        try{
            long count = realm.where(Tyre.class).count();
            if(count>0){
                Tyre t = realm.where(Tyre.class).findFirst();
                if(t!=null){
                    if(t.getUid()!=null && !t.getUid().isEmpty()){
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            Log.d("hasTyre","count="+count);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            realm.close();
        }



        return flag;
    }

//loading data to realm

    synchronized void loadCarbayData(Context context, Handler h, int LOADING_END){
        GlobalParams globalParams = new GlobalParams(context);

        final String url1 = "http://" + globalParams.storage_url + "/carbay/car_bay_data.txt";
        final String url2 =  "http://" + globalParams.storage_url + "/carbay/carbay_ref1.json";
        final String url3 =  "http://" + globalParams.storage_url + "/carbay/carbay_ref2.json";
        final String url4 =  "http://" + globalParams.storage_url + "/carbay/carbay_ref3.json";

        //Log.d("JsonGet", "Realm closed! Realm instances="+Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()));

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        try{
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(TradeInCarbay.class);
                }
            });
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(CarbayBrand.class);
                }
            });
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(CarbayModels.class);
                }
            });
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(CarbayModifications.class);
                }
            });
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(CarbayDataLink.class);
                }
            });
            // Insert multiple items using an InputStream
            Log.d("JsonGet", "Старт загрузки справочника Карбей");
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(url1);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        realm.createAllFromJson(TradeInCarbay.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Log.d("JsonGet", "Старт загрузки регистра Карбей ч1");

            // Insert multiple items using an InputStream

            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(url2);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        realm.createAllFromJson(CarbayBrand.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });


            Log.d("JsonGet", "Старт загрузки регистра Карбей ч2");

            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(url3);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        realm.createAllFromJson(CarbayBrand.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });


            Log.d("JsonGet", "Старт загрузки регистра Карбей ч3");

            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(url4);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        realm.createAllFromJson(CarbayBrand.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            realm.close();
            //Log.d("JsonGet", "Realm closed! Realm instances="+Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()));
        }



        Message msg;
        msg = h.obtainMessage(LOADING_END, 0, 0);
        h.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    synchronized void loadTyres(Context context, Handler h, int LOADING_END){
        GlobalParams globalParams = new GlobalParams(context);

        final String url1 = "http://" + globalParams.storage_url + "/get_tyres_v2.php";

        Log.d("JsonGet", "Старт загрузки справочника шин");

        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.delete(Tyre.class);
                }
            });

            // Insert multiple items using an InputStream
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(url1);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        realm.createAllFromJson(Tyre.class, stream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Message msg;
        msg = h.obtainMessage(LOADING_END, 0, 0);
        h.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

My logcat error message

```
2019-07-12 15:05:09.347 11321-11362/com.lx2.crm E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 5, mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 369098752 offset: 0 in /Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101, .
2019-07-12 15:05:09.350 11321-11362/com.lx2.crm E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been thrown: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 369098752 offset: 0 in /Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
2019-07-12 15:05:09.352 11321-11362/com.lx2.crm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
    Process: com.lx2.crm, PID: 11321
    io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 369098752 offset: 0 in /Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:184)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:254)
        at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:244)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:319)
        at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:282)
        at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:332)
        at com.lx2.crm.LoginPageActivity.loadTyres(LoginPageActivity.java:1154)
        at com.lx2.crm.LoginPageActivity$11.run(LoginPageActivity.java:1001)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: You are not calling disconnect() on your HttpUrlConnection objects in loadCarbay().  I don't know if that is the cause of the memory issue, but it is good practice.  The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) says, "Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused."

Comment: i changed to close HttpUrlConnection, but still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like realm is not set free the memory untill the async task is not finishes. Thats why i had out of memory error even when i try to divide the file im loading. My solution is divide loading file and make async tasks for each of them. Each async task start by callback in previous task. Little bit ugly, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Ilshat, welcome to StackOverflow.

One difference in loadTyres() is that it is using a try-with-resources statement:

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
```

While loadCarbay() is not:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
try{
```

Maybe Realm is not compatible with the try-with-resource statement.
Try having loadCarbay() get the realm instance before the `try` block to see if that resolves the issue.  This is just a guess.

If you do this, remember to also add a finally block with `realm.close();`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've tried to do with try-catch-finally. But still getting out of memory error. It's look like i'm do not closing instance of realm, but i cannot find where..

Answer (score 0):

I found why Realm crashes every time when I get instance - its not enough memory in my device. I was installing my app on another device with large memory and everything works fine.